# VBA Application.Index with array causes type mismatch error 13

Tags: arrays, vba, function, excel, type-mismatch

My macro throws a type mismatch error when I use

```
Myarr= Application.Index(arr,0,1)
```

I have tried adding option explicit and defining the variables as variants but nothing seems to work.

The `arr` array is created from a CSV file and that contains 100000 rows and 11 columns. 
The `arr` looks fine when I check it in the watch window (I can see the values for each row and column)

**Here is the code:**

```
Sub ArrTest()
    Dim Myarr 
    Dim Arr 
    Dim wb As Workbook 
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("F:\People.csv")
    Arr = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Myarr = Application.Index(Arr, 0, 2)
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the worksheet functions have a limit of just over 65k or so when it comes to the upper bound of input arrays, so you may be hitting that.  Works for me with 65k, fails with 66k rows.

```
Sub ArrTest()
    Dim Myarr
    Dim Arr

    Arr = Range("a1:C65000").Value
    Myarr = Application.Index(Arr, 0, 1) '<<< OK

    Arr = Range("a1:C66000").Value
    Myarr = Application.Index(Arr, 0, 1) '<<<fails

End Sub
```

If you want to be able to handle more than 65k upper bound, then you will need to use a loop to populate your array "slice"

Comment: Thank you Tim!  That solved it. The size of the array was the problem.